# Skype for Business links for Teams meeting

Tags: office365, skype-for-business, conferencing

In the company I work for we have conference equipment based on Logitech SmartDock devices which support Skype for Business conferences. You send a meeting invitation to a conference room resource and on the SmartDock you can join the meeting without any other additional equipment.

The issue starts when the meeting was scheduled externally (by a person from cooperating company) using MS Teams. Therefore it would be great to have Skype for Business to MS Teams gateway. Let's say I have a link to MS Teams meeting as input and want to schedule a meeting with conference room using generated SfB link.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless/until the SmartDock itself supports Microsoft Teams. While SfB and Teams are federated in a number of ways, they're still distict architectures. I believe Logitech is already working with the Teams team to get this implemented but I'm not aware of what the status or timeline is.

The best you can do at the moment is dial-in from the conference room system to the Teams meeting.